# Antonym of mandate

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

To *[mandate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandate)* an action is to order it, or to officially require it, usually by means of authority.

**What word could be used to describe ordering that an action *not* be taken?**

For instance, if it is not important to an authoritative body whether a particular action is (or is not) taken, one could say:

> It is not this body's responsibility to mandate or ______ such action.

I've seen *[countermand](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/countermand)* offered as a suggestion, but this seems to have the connotation of revoking or contradicting an earlier order.

Comment: For a verb antonym of _mandate_, you might use _disapprove_, _prohibit_, _forbid_. or _proscribe_. For the opposite of the noun _mandate_, as in a **mandate** to pursue a particular policy, "vote of no confidence" might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Veto is not a word connoting original action. Like countermand, implies that a previous order is stopped or reversed.

For a verb of equal strength as mandate, *prohibit* is apt. Mandate means to command some action, prohibit means to command to refrain from some action.

Mandate (verb) and mandate (noun) are words often used in the US Armed Forces and in American law.  There is an implication of punishment if the person commanded acts contrary to the mandate. Words to command to refrain from some action, used in the same sense in the military and in law, are prohibit (verb) and prohibition (noun).  The word *proscribe* is also correct for a sense of commanding not to act.  Proscribe is used less often,  probably because when spoken, it sounds very close to its antonym, prescribe.

Comment: OP is not asking an original action. Though even it is an original action, it can be proposed and vetoed. Veto is perfectly fine as an antonym.

Comment: He is asking for an original action. His question has a clause doubting the sense of contradiction implied by "countermand".  The opposite of "veto" is "ratify".  Both presuppose some other action first.

Comment: Where is he saying "an original action"? A proposed action can be vetoed. A proposed action can be an original action. You don't have to mix up the terms and start your answer by eliminating other answers given. Yes "prohibiting" is a great answer also and you can just emphasize that.

Comment: @ermanen No action has been proposed.  The example sentence given responds to a proposal regarding whether an action should be actively required or actively prohibited.

Comment: @TimParenti: I don't say it can be only used for "proposed action". It can be used for "intended actions" too. Veto is really an antonym of mandate. I explained in detail.

Comment: mandate does not define a direction of ratification or prohibition. Either can be the subject of a mandate. s/mandate/order/ or s/mandate/command/ and the same concept applies. "What's the mandate?" "Do *this*" or "*Don't* do this." The opposite of mandate is suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The opposite of the verb *mandate* is *[enjoin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/enjoin)*

> (enjoin someone from) Law: Prohibit someone from performing (a particular action) by issuing an injunction.

[*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

As the definition cited above indicates, the associated noun is *injunction.*

Comment: Enjoin can mean also to command, same as mandate.  In the law, an injunction can be a court order to take action or to refrain from taking action. It is one of those self-antonyms, like "sanction".

Comment: @Theresa So true. But when used as a verb as opposed to noun, to enjoin usually means to stop rather than compel, as in *enjoin someone from doing something*.

Comment: @Erik, My idea of frequency of use is skewed: I am a lawyer and the daughter of the Sergeant Major. I've been the "mandatee" for most of my life.

Comment: I've usually seen it as *enjoin to* rather than *enjoin from*. While it **is** an antonym when used with *from*, it's certainly ambiguous.

Comment: ***Enjoin*** is a great word, but perhaps not quite the best fit here due to the fact that it's typically found with a preposition like *from*.

Comment: I agree that it would not fit many situations, especially since it is a legally laden word. I do like @Theresa 's *prohibit* for a broader coverage.

Answer (score 1):

> "I forbidded it!" 
>   -- Rajesh Kuthrapali

*countermand* means to reverse the effect of a previously issued mandate.

*proscribe* means to forbid.

*anathemize* means to create a serious moral stigma against.

*disapprove* can mean to express a dislike for, or to withhold necessary official approval

*veto* means to override the approval of another body

Answer (score 0):

You can impose (or apply) a [*moratorium*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/moratorium):

> Definition of *moratorium* in English:
>
> Syllabification: mor·a·to·ri·um
>   Pronunciation: /ˌmôrəˈtôrēəm    /
>   NOUN (plural moratoriums or moratoria /-ˈtôrēə/)
>
> 1 A temporary prohibition of an activity:
>   *an indefinite **moratorium** on the use of drift nets*
>
> MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *It was simply due to the fact that the British, American and Soviet governments agreed a temporary **moratorium** on all nuclear testing in October 1958.*
>
> *In 2003 the US government put a temporary **moratorium** on the development of specialist hospitals that are partly owned by the doctors using them.*
>
> *A temporary **moratorium** on new computers has been imposed by the service.*
>
> 1.1 *Law* A legal authorization to debtors to postpone payment.
>
> MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *For Germany, the economic and financial crisis led US President Hoover to announce on 21 June 1931 a one-year **moratorium** for reparation payments.*
>
> *There's nothing inconsistent with the Government now saying there should be a **moratorium** and a payment of the lower amount.*
>
> *The downside of a **moratorium** is that when it is lifted, payments are bunched up and the cost of borrowing could rise, meaning countries will find it even harder reduce their debt.*

(Definitions and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Imposing a ***moratorium*** seems to imply that there is some continuing action to be stopped.  This is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Because mandate stops at *command* and not command *to do*, mandate is a poor choice for asking for an effectively understood antonym in the context presented. Indeed, it can be an implied "do this", but the definition stops with authoritative and command.

What does that mean?

It means mandate is more synonymous with *order* or *command* than with *ratification*. One can mandate that an action occurs just as authoritatively as mandate that an action is prohibited. That's exactly how mandate is used.

Answer (score -1):

***Veto*** would be the verb that you are looking for.

> *tr.v.* To forbid or prohibit authoritatively.
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/veto</sup>

*Veto*, as a noun, is the power to prevent or stop an official action or legislation. For example, an action can be proposed and mandated or it can be proposed and vetoed. Vetoing emphasizes an authoritative prohibition. Similarly, ***interdict*** has this sense and it is used both in ecclesiastical and legal contexts as well.

You can also consider ***rescind***, if you are officially ending or cancelling. (Synonyms: revoke, repeal, annul)

Addition from SrJoven:

> The veto is not simply saying "I reject this!" It's actually saying "I am issuing my authority to prohibit the action from occurring." This actually makes more sense this way, especially in light of what it effectively does. Authoritatively prohibit. A mandate is an authoritative command to do something. A veto is considered "You aren't authorized to do this."

Comment: I might go along with this. I wouldn't think about it in prohibitive terms if it was said to me. (I'd think of veto more of reject/deny than to prohibit, if it was told to me). This is interesting, though. The veto is not simply saying "I reject this!" It's actually saying "I am issuing my authority to prohibit the action from occurring." This actually makes more sense this way, especially in light of what it effectively does. Authoritatively prohibit. A mandate is an authoritative command to do something. A veto is considered "You aren't authorized to do this."

Comment: @SrJoven: Finally, someone understands me. Thanks for helping to clarify what I mean.

Comment: The action is neither an official one nor is it legislation.  While ***veto*** has legislative connotations which would go better with a verb indicating official approval, like *ratify*, I think ***interdict*** mostly avoids this problem.

Comment: @TimParenti: Veto can be used in non-legal context too. For example, Parents can veto an action of their children.

Comment: @ermanen Yes, but a parent vetoing a child's action seems more opposite to a parent *approving* of such an action, rather than *mandating* it.

Comment: @TimParenti: Yes but we are talking about another context. You can approve or prohibit also. You can allow or prohibit. You can allow or veto. You can pass or veto. There are a lot of alternatives. The context in your question was more of a legal context though. "Prohibit" is more general, I just mentioned "veto" as a more specific prohibition.

Comment: @ermanen An authoritative body is not necessarily a legal one.

Comment: @TimParenti: Yes. Your parents can be an authoritative body. Veto can be used in that context, we talked about this. But mandate is used more in legal-context, so the opposite is more of a legal-context.